# Wordpress Rewrite Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function add_new_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^gourmet/area/([^/]*)/genre/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=gourmet&gourmet_area=$matches[1]&gourmet_genre=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^gourmet/area/([^/]*)/genre/([^/]*)/type/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=gourmet&gourmet_area=$matches[1]&gourmet_genre=$matches[2]&food_type=$matches[3]','top');
}
```

So I have something like this, but when I go to: http://www.site.com/gourmet/area/Test1/genre/Test2/type/Test3

I have a var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['gourmet_area'];), and for some reason it's not passing the last variable.

It posts: Test1, and Test2 but not Test3. If I remove the first rule, it will dump Test3.

How do I get it to include Test1, Test2 if those are only available?

Answer (score 0):

Add some dollar signs to the end of your regular expressions. The regular expression is then only valid if the path ends with a trailing slash or any non slash character.

```
function add_new_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^gourmet/area/([^/]*)/genre/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?post_type=gourmet&gourmet_area=$matches[1]&gourmet_genre=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^gourmet/area/([^/]*)/genre/([^/]*)/type/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?post_type=gourmet&gourmet_area=$matches[1]&gourmet_genre=$matches[2]&food_type=$matches[3]','top');
}
```

The dollar sign marks the ending of a string.